# Jquery Lightbox not showing

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am very new to jquery as well as stackoverflow.

I am trying to create a lightbox by myself. I have succeded in adding lightbox structure using jquery as follows.....

```
var patch= $(
        '<div id="Adi-patch" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); text-align: center; color: white;"></div>');
    $("#wrapper").before(patch);
    patch.html(
        '<span id="Adi-close-btn" style="position: absolute; right: 1em; font-size: 2em; color: white; cursor: pointer;">&#9587;</span>\
        <div id="Adi-content" style="background: gray; position: relative; left: 50%; margin-left: -25%; width: 50%; height: 90%; overflow: hidden;"></div>\
        <div id="Adi-prev-btn" style="background: black; position: absolute; top: 50%; font-size: 2em; margin-top: -1em; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;">&#10094;</div>\
        <div id="Adi-next-btn" style="background: black; position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 0px; font-size: 2em; margin-top: -1em; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;">&#10095;</div>\
        <div id="Adi-caption" style="padding: 5px;">Sample caption</div>'
    );
    patch.css({"display": "none"});
```

But then I am stuck at revealing the content on the click event. I have tried....

```
<!-- Show Lightbox structure on anchor click event   -->
    $('#wrapper a').click(function(){
        patch.fadeToggle();
    });
```

The problem is the structure just flickers and vanishes off. It dosen't stay there. Please suggest what should I do to solve this issue. Or else please direct me to the solution if it has already been discussed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle. It will be hard to debug your code without seeing the html.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle. I m new to jsfiddle as well, but have given a try

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/daadymse/

Comment: As you would see, the result adds lightbox structure but it vanishes immidiately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because your hyperlinks were left empty, redirecting to the same page.

You can use several placeholders and if you search you'll find plenty of discussions here about what's the best option. Most people just use "#" but be aware that it will auto-scroll you to the top of the page.

Don't forget to add the same listener to the close button:

```
$('#wrapper a, #Adi-close-btn').click(function() {
  patch.fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has worked. But I did not understand why in the world does the default behaviour of links has to be that wierd. Or in other words this is not at all intutive. Can you share some online tutorial on understanding the logic of this particular method.